# How to know rotation in flv video

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, exiftool

I need to know the rotation angle in flv video. I am using exiftool but it does not show rotation tag for flv videos. Any way to know it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As far as I know, there are no standard FLV tags for rotation, and I don't know any tool that would inject such metadata (including flvmeta, which I wrote). This is a good idea though, if this data is stored somewhere in the video data (AVC SPS for example) I might give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/)

In command mode, you can use:

```
mediainfo test.flv | grep Rotation
```

to get rotation angle info, or if correctly recalled, you can use:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Rotation%" test.flv
```

to extract the info directly.

Try whether it helps.